# Miracast receiver software for Windows

Tags: windows, screen-sharing

I have a Windows laptop which has a Wi-Fi NIC inside, that's all the hardware that is needed to become a Miracast receiver.

Now I need some software that runs on Windows 7 and that supports this [stupid protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast)* and can turn my laptop into a "TV" that my phone (Windows Phone, but Miracast is also supported on Android) will recognize. Price doesn't matter as long as it's not something extreme like 500$.

Thanks.

---

*stupid because it's branded under a zillion different names, looks like a proprietary and obfuscated technology that's only designed to sell dongles and these not-so-Smart TVs.

Comment: Is your computer widi compatible? http://www.anandtech.com/show/6312/intels-widi-35-much-faster-usb-miracast-support-and-new-receivers

Answer (score 1):

I have used [AirServer](http://www.airserver.com/) for recording Miracast from my phone.  We are exploring using this so that students learning Python can see their Raspberry Pi's screen on their laptop (saving money).

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature that is supported in Windows 10. Open up "Settings" and browse to **System** > **Projecting to this PC**. Change the **Always Off** option to **Available everywhere on secure networks**.

When an attempt is made to connect via Miracast, a notification will pop up in the action center asking for permissions. After accepting, the cast will be displayed on the primary monitor.